# Using elementaryOS with systemd-boot

Tags: grub

Situation: I want to change my bootloader from GRUB2 to systemd-boot as it is faster and more lightweight.

Problem: I do not know where to start.

Question: How do I change my bootloader from GRUB2 to systemd-boot (or any other bootloaders)? Tutorials will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your hardware situation(EFI or MBR etc).
So, in general, follow the Arch Linux wiki page for tutorial.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-boot

In case you are trying to do this on Mac as I did. Go here.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mac#Using_the_native_Apple_bootloader_with_systemd-boot_.28Recommended.29